# Не хотят отображаться метки ObjectManager

Tags: yandex-maps-api

На локальном компьютере те же самые файлы, взятые из песочницы без какого либо редактирования не отображают метки по данным из json файла. В чем может быть причина?
Понимаю формулировка вопроса так себе, но абсолютно идентичные файлы как в примере песочницы Яндекс карт.

Comment: Есть какая-нибудь ошибка в консоли? Можете показать "те же самые файлы", скриншот?

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на правильность кода каждой записи и особое внимание! после последнего блока не должно быть запятой.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [

        {"type": "Feature", "id": 0, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [44.61156, 40.066137]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "Пункт выдачи заказов Экиплэнд", "balloonContentBody": "<p></font><strong>Бесплатная доставка при заказе от 7000 руб.</strong></p><p>- Оплата после примерки<br>- Гарантия, возврат<br><br>Адрес: Россия, Республика Адыгея, Майкоп, Пионерская улица, 385А<br>Режим работы:Пн-Пт 09:00-20:00, Сб 10:00-16:00 (тел пункта выдачи +79282824777)</p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Наш телефон: </font><strong>8(800)7773067</strong><br><br>От остановки «Чкалова»,перейти на ул. Пионерскую, повернуть  на лево,пройти 500 метров до  офиса.", "clusterCaption": "<strong>Пункт выдачи заказов Экиплэнд", "hintContent": "<strong>Пункт выдачи заказов Экиплэнд</strong>"}},
                      {"type": "Feature", "id": 884, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [66.529293, 66.626994]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "Пункт выдачи заказов Экиплэнд", "balloonContentBody": "<p></font><strong>Расчет стоимости доставки при оформлении корзины</strong></p><p>- Гарантия, возврат<br><br>Адрес: Россия, Ямало-Ненецкий автономный округ, Салехард, улица Республики, 76<br>Режим работы:Пн-Пт 10:00-19:00, Сб 10:00-16:00 (тел пункта выдачи +73492237333)</p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Наш телефон: </font><strong>8(800)7773334</strong><br><br>ТЦ «Мегаполис»", "clusterCaption": "<strong>Пункт выдачи заказов Экиплэнд", "hintContent": "<strong>Пункт выдачи заказов Экиплэнд</strong>"}}

    ]
}
```

Карта работает по адресу: https://ekipland.ru/map/hiddendiv.html